# Load the values twice into two input fields onload

Tags: javascript, html

I am using local storage to save the username in the first-page.html and retrieving it into the second-page.html

But if I have two or more places in my second-page.html where I want the username to be retrieved, how can I achieve it using two different ids. Since the id once used cannot be used in another input field.
Can anyone please help.

Index.html:

```
    <script>
        function save(){
            var fieldValue = document.getElementById('user').value;
            localStorage.setItem('text', fieldValue);
        }
    </script>


<div class="form-group" id="login-fields">
  <div class="cols-sm-10">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"><span class="text--white glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></i>
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input class="view sign-in-app" type="submit" value="Sign In" id="submit-login" onclick="save()" />
```

SecondPage.html

```
    <script>
        function load(){
            var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('text');
            if(storedValue){
                document.getElementById('here').value = storedValue;
            }
        }
    </script>

<body onload="load()">
<!-- first div -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="cols-sm-10">
    <div class="input-group">                     
      <input type="text" name="userName" id="here" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 <!-- second div --> 
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="cols-sm-10">
    <div class="input-group"> // change the id here                    
      <input type="text" name="userName" id="here" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required> 
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: You are not allowed to use an HTML `id` attribute value more than once on a page.

Comment: @PHPglue I think that's what I asked, I want to change the id in the second place but also retrieve the username there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give each element different ids, really. No problem with that. And then when you set, set both:

```
if (storedValue) {
    document.getElementById('here').value = storedValue;
    document.getElementById('my-other-id').value = storedValue;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to test, will let you know if that worked. But I am sure it would work.